# concat typescript files in certain order after compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, concatenation

I would like achieve with gulp this:

1. compile ts to js, this is not problem
2. then concat js files in certain order, this is problem

I am creating angular application hence I need concat ts files in certain order.

```
gulp.src(paths.appTs) //src contains files in right order
    .pipe(print())
    .pipe(tsc(tsOptions))
    .pipe(print()) //after compilation are files in bad order
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(concant("app.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/app"))
    .pipe(print());
```

The best will be possible use [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref)

Answer (score 1):

> then concat js files in certain order, this is problem

I don't recommend using `out` / `outFile` (https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md) as manually ordering TS files can be a **pain**.

Highly recommend using modules e.g. `--module commonjs` and leverage something like webpack to build for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Order of files can be enforced by adding

```
///<reference path="relative/path/to/file.ts" />
```

At the top of your `.ts` files.

For more information, please see

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-across-files